# Store Auth::user()-id in DB using SQL query in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to store `Auth::user()->id` on the default column `user_id` in the SQL query shown below.

I tried to set put like this but does not send any data to the database.

```
public function saveLoadingsData() {

    //Validate for a valid Post Request
    if (isset($_POST['orderNumber']) && isset($_POST['Truck']) && isset($_POST['receiptNumber']) && isset($_POST['items'])) {

        // {"orderNumber":"CRS1104200001","agentId":"3","items":[{"itemId":"4","itemName":"Embe","quantity":"13"}]}

        $orderNumber = $_POST['orderNumber'];
        $items = $_POST['items'];
        $receiptNumber = $_POST['receiptNumber'];
        $Truck = $_POST['Truck'];
        $driverName = $_POST['driverName'];
        
        foreach ($items as $singleItem) {
            $data = array('order_no' => $orderNumber,'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,"receiptNumber" => $receiptNumber, "Truck" => $Truck, "driverName" => $driverName, "pid" => $singleItem['itemId'], "qty" => $singleItem['quantity']);

            // print_r($data);
            DB::table('loadings')->insert($data);

            // return redirect()->back();
        }
        // return redirect()->back();

        echo "Success";
    }
```

My ajax function

```
 $("#btnSaveOrder").on('click', function(e){

var orderNumber=$("#order_no").val();
var receiptNumber=$("#receiptNumber").val();
var Truck=$("#Truck").val();
var driverName=$("#driverName").val();
var jsonData=convertTableToJson();

$.ajax('/api/loading/saveLoadingsData', {
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    orderNumber:orderNumber,
    receiptNumber:receiptNumber,
     Truck:Truck,
    driverName:driverName,
    items:jsonData
  },
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {

    alert("Data Saved");
    document.location.reload(true);

  },
  error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    console.log(errorMessage);

  }
  });

});

 var convertTableToJson = function(){
   var rows = [];
   $('table#tableSelectedItems tr').each(function(i, n){
    if (i!=0) {
      var $row = $(n);
      rows.push({
      itemId: $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
      itemName:   $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
      quantity:    $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),

    });
  }
});
return rows;
};
```

My api route

```
Route::post('loading/saveLoadingsData', 'LoadingController@saveLoadingsData');
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hurts my eyes when I see $_POST on this framework. Why don't you use ```Request $request```? Did you checked the logs?

Comment: Is your user logged-in? What error do you get?

Comment: @hmrneves, i pull this data via json format that why i use post,

Comment: @LobsterBaz, nothing return back i have. Append table so i take that data in json format

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the following

Pass the $request object in your method and log all object, maybe are missing data and for that reason it does not meet the condition:

```js
saveLoadingsData(Request $request){
   Log::info(json_encode($request->all()));`
}
```

Then check your logs files to see the result in /storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: Let me send my form code, and understand logic, because i have a form which has append table